# Функции на C в linux

Tags: c, linux

С помощью каких функций можно:

1. Найти процесс;
2. Найти границы памяти процесса;
3. Найти в памяти строку;
4. Вычитать строку, следующую за ней

Забыл указать, для **модуля ядра**!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону /proc

1) Свой pid = getpid();

2) Потом почитайте (поизучайте в доках из inet) , например /proc/**pid**/status

3,4) Читать файл с именем mem (из /proc/**pid**/ для процесса (у меня) не получается (впрочем я не изучал этот вопрос (сейчас пробую из терминала), может быть это вообще не тот файл), боюсь, что для чтения памяти Вам придется изучать ptrace().

Функции понадобятся видимо самые простые: open(), read(), strcmp() ...

Comment: насчет ptrace я согласен с вами, мне нужно будет использовать эту функцию, а вот можно про 1 и 2 пункты поподробнее? я не очень понял их(

Comment: Да я прочитал Ваш вопрос еще без дополнения о **модулях ядра**, думал Вы об обычной программе. Поэтому ответ не корректный (хотя м.б. в ядре тоже есть доступ к /proc).

Хотел посоветовать посмотреть код отладчика (gdb), заглянул сюда и увидел, что ответ не в тему.

Answer (score 0):

Найти процесс можно только анализируя директорию /proc. Однако ядро не разрешит одному процессу просто так залезть в виртуальную память другого процесса.

Comment: хм,а как тогда быть?

Comment: есть несколько видов межпроцессных связей. Попробуйте почитать про разделенную память. Хотя Вы не описали задачу, которую нужно решить. Конкретнее сказать не могу.

Comment: отвечаю только здесь.

Comment: Написать драйвер, осуществляющий поиск в памяти указанного по имени процесса указанной при загрузке строки. В случае обнаружения драйвер должен сохранить следующую за обнаруженной строку в файл. Искомая строка и имя процесса указываются при загрузке драйвера.  
это мое задание

Comment: А, ну так и писали бы, что модуль пишите. К сожалению, ядерным программированием никогда не занимался.

Comment: да вот что-то забыл указать об этом(((